# JSF custom component not updating value for AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, composite-component

I'm trying to figure out how to extend BalusC's `inputDate` example [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html).  I'd like the component to update the value on each change of one of the dropdowns and fire an event, something like this:

```
<balusc:inputDate value="#{myBean.date}">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="someOtherComponent"/>
</balusc:inputDate>
<h:outputText id="someOtherComponent" value="#{myBean.formattedDate}"/>
```

The `someOtherComponent` depends on values that get updated when `#{myBean.date}` gets updated.  (See note at the end on `update=` complications.)

I believe this would require modifying the `inputDate` component to first of all announce in the `<cc:interface>` section that it has a `valueChange` behavior, something like this:

```
<cc:clientBehavior name="valueChange" targets="day month year" event="change"/>
```

This gets the event to fire, but it is not enough to get the value updated, and I am at a loss as to what to change to make it both change the value and fire the event.  So the question is:

**How do you add the ability for a composite component to live-update its value so they are available for AJAX events?**

The environment I'm running with is Windows 7, Java 1.7.0_80, Tomcat 7.0.68 with its version of EL, JSF Mojarra 2.2.8-14, jstl 1.2, Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2).

---

P.S. I've noticed that when adding `f:ajax` or `p:ajax` elements with `render=` or `update=`, it's difficult to get the outside components to refresh.  Even the ugly workaround of `:#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:someOtherComponent` doesn't work, but the very messy `:#{component.namingContainer.clientId.substring(0, component.namingContainer.clientId.lastIndexOf(':'))}:someOtherComponent` does.